# Can not convert pdf file into byte[] in spring

Tags: java, spring, forms, multipart

I am facing issues while converting a `pdf` file in to a `byte array` to save it in the database. I am getting below error:

> "Failed to convert property value of type
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile
>   to required type byte[] for property file; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile
>   to required type byte for property file[0]: PropertyEditor
>   [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor]
>   returned inappropriate value of type
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile"

My code:

-Controller

```
    @PostMapping("/recruitment")
public String addingNewCandidateToDataBase(@RequestParam MultipartFile file, @Valid @ModelAttribute("candidate") CandidateDTO candidateDTO, BindingResult result) throws IOException {
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "recruitment";
    }
    if(candidateDTO.getAgreement() == null){
        result.rejectValue("agreement", null, "Aby aplikować musisz wyrazić zgodę.");
        return "recruitment";
    }
    if(!file.getOriginalFilename().endsWith("pdf")){
        result.rejectValue("file", null, "Plik musi posiadać rozszerzenie .pdf!");
        return "recruitment";
    }
    candidateDTO.setContentType(file.getContentType());
    candidateDTO.setFile(file.getBytes());
    candidateDTO.setFileName(file.getName());
    candidateService.creatingNewCandidate(candidateDTO);
    return "redirect/recruitment?complete";
}
```

Jsp file

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Recruitment</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form:form enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="candidate" method="post">
<center>
    <c:if test="${param.complete != null}">
        <h1><p style="color: greenyellow">Twoje zgłoszenie zostało wysłane! Dziękujemy.</p></h1>
    </c:if>
    <h1>Dane kandydata</h1></center>
<p><form:label path="firstName">Imię*</form:label></p>
<p><form:input path="firstName"/><form:errors path="firstName"/><form:errors path="lastName"/></p>
<br>

<p><form:label path="lastName">Nazwisko*</form:label></p>
<p><form:input path="lastName"/></p>
<br>

<p><form:label path="email">E-mail*</form:label><form:errors path="email"/></p>
<p><form:input path="email"/></p>
<br>

<p><form:label path="phoneNumber">Telefon komórkowy</form:label><form:errors path="phoneNumber"/></p>
<p><form:input path="phoneNumber"/></p>
<br>

<p><form:label path="experience">Czy posiadasz doświadczenie? Jeśli jak to ile i jakie.*</form:label><form:errors
        path="experience"/></p>
<p><form:textarea path="experience"/></p>
<br>

<p><form:label path="position">Na jakie stanowisko chcesz aplikować?*</form:label><form:errors path="position"/></p>
<p><form:input path="position"/></p>
<br>

<p><form:label path="file">CV*</form:label><form:errors path="file"/></p>
<p><form:input type="file" path="file"/> </p>
<br>

<center><h1>Dodatkowe pytania</h1></center>
<br>

<p><form:label path="whenIsReadyToStart">Od kiedy jesteś gotowy by zacząć pracę?</form:label><form:errors
        path="whenIsReadyToStart"/></p>
<p><form:input path="whenIsReadyToStart"/></p>
<br>

<p><form:label path="grossExpectation">Jakie są Twoje oczekiwania finansowe (brutto)?</form:label><form:errors
        path="grossExpectation"/></p>
<p><form:input path="grossExpectation"/></p>
<br>

<center><h2>Zgoda</h2></center>
<div class="form-group form-check">
    <form:checkbox path="agreement" value="${candidate.agreement}"/> ${candidate.agreement}
</div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">WYŚLIJ</button>
    </form:form>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing to create a [`MultipartResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-multipart).

> `MultipartResolver` from the `org.springframework.web.multipart` package is a strategy for parsing multipart requests including file uploads
>
> To enable multipart handling, you need to declare a `MultipartResolver` bean in your `DispatcherServlet` Spring configuration with a name of `multipartResolver`.

Try to add the following in your Spring MVC beans config

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
```

Comment: still doesnt works or i am doing something wrong :(